# ASP.NET MVC CheckBox List sending always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to create a table with items and checkboxes to select these items. I am including these checkboxes in a list but this list is always returning null. Thank you very much for your help.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var expenseTypesView = new ViewExpenseTypesAndSelection
    {
        ExpensesTypes = _context.ExpenseType.ToList(), 
    };       
    return View(expenseTypesView);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectExpensesTypes( ViewExpenseTypesAndSelection SelectedExpenses)
{
    var entry = new userSpecificExpenses();
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var item in SelectedExpenses.SelectedExpenses)
    {
        if(item)
        {
            entry.expenseTypeId = i;
            entry.UtilisateurId= User.Identity.GetUserId();
            _context.UserspecificExpenses.Add(entry);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        i++;
    }
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model MBT.ViewModels.ViewExpenseTypesAndSelection
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectExpensesTypes", "ExpenseTypes"))
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Expense</th>
                <th class="text-center">Include</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.ExpensesTypes.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Model.ExpensesTypes[i].Type
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SelectedExpenses[i])
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: What are your models for `ExpenseType` and `SelectedExpenses`? Using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SelectedExpenses[i])` makes no sense. Your `ExpensesType` model needs a property (say) `bool IsSelected` and then its `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExpensesTypes[i].IsSelected)` and then you would also need at least one other hidden input for the `ExpensesType` ID property

Answer (score 0):

You sending `ViewExpenseTypesAndSelection` almost null just with `ExpensesTypes` and then post it back to your post method. It means you send null and receive null.
So what is wrong with that?